# Give parent object the same classes like child object with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, addclass

In a Wordpress theme I check if an image is linked, and if so, I want to add the the same class to the image link (parent):

```
if($("img[class*='wp-image-']").closest("a").length ) {
    $(".alignleft").parent().addClass('alignleft');
    $(".aligncenter").parent().addClass('aligncenter');
    $(".alignright").parent().addClass('alignright');
    $(".alignnone").parent().addClass('alignnone');
}
```

But in some cases the image (child) has some more classes. I want to give the link (parent) all these classes, too - automatically. Is that possible with jQuery?

Comment: can you include an html or demo for the misbehaving parts of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get The class of element as an array and add it to the parent:

```
var $elem= $("img[class*='wp-image-']");
var className = $elem.attr('class');
var classList = className.split(/\s+/);
for (var i = 0; i < classList.length; i++) {
    $elem.closest("a").addClass(classList[i]);
}
```

If you want to do this automatically with all images, you have to mdify the code to iterate through all images.